# Maintaining a project which uses %1$s in a string in the Strings.XML file.

Tags: java, android, xml

I am maintaining a project which has a strings which uses %1$s to add in another string to it and %1$d.

On some views it literally shows up as %1$s and %1$d where as others are not effected.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Not filling those parameters. [getString(int, Object...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: It is strange because i am... mTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.some_string), getString(R.string.some_otherstring));

Comment: If you know where that happens, debug that line and e.g. log all the strings (format, parameter, combined). Something might be null, or that line is not executed and you have set the format string in xml (which would print it as is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved: I accidentally duplicated the views. so only one of them was being formatted.